# Regularity of the distance from the boundary in singular riemannian manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, sub-riemannian-geometry

I am looking for references related with the regularity of the distance from the boundary in singular Riemannian manifolds.

I assume the following setting. $(M,g)$ is a Riemannian manifold, with smooth boundary $\partial M$. The metric $g$ is smooth in the interior of $M$, but is singular on $\partial M$ (in a sense that will be clear soon).

We assume that we still have a "normal vector field to the boundary", that is vector field $N_q \in T_q M$ for $q  \in \partial M$ such that the metric $g(N,N) =1$ is well defined (i.e. $g$ remains a well defined metric on a subspace $\Delta_q$, at any point $q \in \partial M$, and $\Delta_q \subset T_qM$ is transversal to the tangent space to the boundary $T_q \partial M$).

This covers many different type of degeneracy. To give examples, let $M = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{S}^1 \}$, $\partial M = \{x = 0\}$.

1. conic manifolds: the metric is of the form $g=dx^2+ x^2 dy^2$
2. Grushin structures: the metric is of the form $g=dx^2 + \tfrac{1}{x^2} dy^2$
3. $\sqrt{\text{Grushin}}$ structures: the metric is of the form $g= dx^2 + \tfrac{1}{x} dy^2$

Notice that (2) is a particular case of "almost Riemannian structure", where the metric can be defined by a smooth (on $M \cup \partial M$) orthonormal frame $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ where some of them vanish at the boundary, while (3) does not belong to this class. Indeed (3) is generated by $X_1 = \partial_x$ and $X_2 = \sqrt{x} \partial y$, which is not smooth on $M \cup \partial M$ ($g$ is nevertheless smooth on $\partial M$ as well).

The distance $d(x,y)$ for $x \in \partial M$ is still well defined as the infimum of the lengths due to the existence of $N$ and it is finite.

What is known about the regularity of the distance from the boundary $$D(p):= \inf_{q \in \partial M} d(q,p), \qquad \text{?} $$

We know that it is smooth on a small tubular neighborhood of $\partial M$, in the "almost-Riemannian" case. We suspect this to be true in full generality (under our assumption on the existence of the normal field $N$), but we were unable to find a reference (or to produce an unified proof).

Notice that, in all the examples above, $D = x$, so it is smooth.